# Rust cannot borrow (variable) as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable

Tags: rust, ownership

I've encountered similar error like milion times, and usually putting curly braces around problematic code has worked, however I've encountered rather strange case:

```
fn breadth_first_index(
    root: CargoCrateVersionNode,
    redis_connection: &mut Connection,
    show_dev_dependencies: bool,
    show_build_dependencies: bool,
) {
    let mut already_included_versions = vec![root.ccv_version_id];
    let mut dependency_tree: Vec<(Option<DependsOnEdge>, CargoCrateVersionNode)> =
        vec![(None, root)];

    let mut i = 0;
    while i < dependency_tree.len() {
        let (edge_to_current_dependency, current_dependency) = &dependency_tree[i];

        let mut command =
            format!("match (main:CargoCrateVersion)-[edge:depends_on]->(connected) where main.ccv_version_id = {} and (edge.doe_kind = 0", current_dependency.ccv_version_id);
        if show_dev_dependencies {
            command.push_str(" or edge.doe_kind = 2");
        }
        if show_build_dependencies {
            command.push_str(" or edge.doe_kind = 1");
        }
        command.push_str(" )");
        command.push_str(" return edge, connected");

        let redis_answ = redis_connection.graph_query(GRAPH_NAME, command).unwrap();
        let mut parsed_dependencies =
            CargoCrateVersionNode::parse_bulk(&redis_answ.data, "connected").unwrap();
        let mut parsed_edges = DependsOnEdge::parse_bulk(&redis_answ.data, "edge").unwrap();

        while !parsed_dependencies.is_empty() {
            let dependency = parsed_dependencies.remove(0);
            let edge = parsed_edges.remove(0);

            if already_included_versions.contains(&dependency.ccv_version_id) {
                continue;
            }
            // This if let causes the error.
            // I've tried putting curly braces around this block of code, however I was unsucesfull.
            if let Some(edge_to_current) = &edge_to_current_dependency {
                if edge_to_current.doe_optional {
                    if let Some(edge_features) = &edge_to_current.doe_with_features {
                        println!("{:?}", edge_features);
                    }
                }
            }

            already_included_versions.push(dependency.ccv_version_id);
            dependency_tree.push((Some(edge), dependency));
        }
        i += 1;
    }
    println!("---- Dependency tree ----");
    for l in dependency_tree {
        println!("{:?}", l.1);
    }
}
```

I am aware about mutability and lifetimes, however I do not understand why there's error in my case. I'm using rustc 1.63 and rust edition 2021.

I'm getting the following error

```
226 |         let (edge_to_current_dependency, current_dependency) = &dependency_tree[i];
    |                                                                 --------------- immutable borrow occurs here...
253 |                 if let Some(edge_to_current) = edge_to_current_dependency {
    |                                                -------------------------- immutable borrow later used here
...
262 |             dependency_tree.push((Some(edge), dependency));
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `package_finder` due to previous error
```

I know what is happening. I'm getting reference to an element inside mutable list and then achieve immutable reference to this reference, while still mutating the list afterwards. I tried solving this with adding curly braces around the if let statement, however I keep getting the same error. I feel like this code should compile after putting curly braces around if let, however it does not. I'm asking on SO, because I (kinda naively) believe that this is error with inner workings of the rust compiler.

Edit: I was able to solve it by replacing the problematic line with dirrect access to the array, however this is not ideal by any means. I feel like this is indeed bug inside the compiler, am I right?

```
if let Some(edge_to_current) = &dependency_tree[i].0 {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no bug with the compiler (at least, with the code you're presenting). The problem is that you're still not familiar with the rules of borrowing and ownership on Rust.

I think you would like to read this one:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html

But, addressing your error, this line:
`let (edge_to_current_dependency, current_dependency) = &dependency_tree[i];`

you're destructuring elements that are behind a shared reference. In other words, your let statement are holding references.

You borrow (just `&`) your vector with `&dependency_tree`, and then access the element on it. There's no need to do it. Just `take ownership` of the element that you're accesing (means, remove your `&`).

One thing: Curly braces around your `if let` does not solve anything. You're just creating an inner scope, but again, your accessing a shared reference.